# How to pass a map in thymeleaf (spring 4)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to pass a map from a properties file using the thymeleaf template engine.

Exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'title' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.String' - maybe not public?
```

provider.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html th:include="receiver :: receiver(#{site})"></html>
```

receiver.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html th:fragment="receiver(map)">
    <head>
        <title th:text="${map.title}">title</title>
    </head>
    <body th:text="${map.body}">
        body
    </body>
</html>
```

messages.properties:

```
site.title = Any title
site.body = Any body
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class StartController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String start(Model model) {
        return "provider";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It simply like in Java. Key and value of the Map

```
<div th:each="userEnrty: ${userMap}">
<p th:text="${userEntry.key}">No Id!</p>
<p th:text="${userEntry.value}">No Name!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work out for me.
I get this message now: Property or field 'title' cannot be found on null

I edited receiver to this:

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html th:fragment="receiver(map)" th:each="entry: ${map}">
<head>
    <title th:text="${entry.title}">title</title>
</head>
<body th:text="${entry.body}">
body
</body>
</html>

Comment: NOT ${entry.title} . Use ${entry.key}

Comment: Map(Key, Value) not Map(title, body)

Comment: I don't want to iterate over all key-value-pairs. I just want to get the value of "title" out of the map, which is my fragment parameter "map".

Comment: Show your controller and Map

Comment: Where is your Map?

Comment: In the messages.properties file.

Comment: Try #{site.title} with out  th:fragment="receiver(map)" or even th:alt-title="#{title.application}"

Comment: It's in my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that property-files are processed as Map. So 'site' wasn't a map at all.

My solution now is to pass the name of the variable-prefi and get the keys by thymeleaf preprocessing.

provider.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html th:include="receiver :: receiver('site')"></html>
```

receiver.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html th:fragment="receiver(mapname)">
    <head>
        <title th:text="#{__${mapname}__.title}">title</title>
    </head>
    <body th:text="#{__${mapname}__.body}">
        body
    </body>
</html>
```

messages.properties

```
site.title = Any title
site.body = Any body
```